# Can't establish an SSH tunnel with python + sshtunnel

Tags: python, ssh, rsa, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to establish an SHH tunnel to a jump-server with the following piece of code:

```py
import sshtunnel

server = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('jump host', jump_port),  
    ssh_username = 'my_user_name',
    ssh_pkey = '~/.ssh/id_rsa',  
    ssh_private_key_password = 'my private key pwd',  
    remote_bind_address = ('remote_host', remote_port),  
    local_bind_address = ('localhost', local_port)
    )
```

But repeatedly getting an error:

```
| ERROR   | Password is required for key C:\Users\<my_local_user_name>/.ssh\id_rsa
```

I've checked several similar questions and tried the suggested solutions but with no luck yet.

I'm sure that my RSA key file and password are both correct.
I've checked that with the following code:

```py
import paramiko
pkey='C:/Users/<my_local_user_name>/.ssh/id_rsa'
key=paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(pkey, 'my private key pwd')
```

It works and successfully creates the `key` object.

I've also examined the code of `sshtunnel` and have found the only place where such an error message is fired:

- https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/aa7342e55e49529fea020a09ba8f1eed33eb896f/sshtunnel.py#L1314

[image]

As far as I understand this call to `pkey_class.from_private_key_file` in 1304 line should work well just as my direct above call to `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file`, but for some reasons it fires the `PasswordRequiredException` here.

I've also checked the paramiko source code and have found that this exception is only raised when the key file is encrypted and the password is None, and I think it's not my case as I specify the password correctly.

Passing `allow_agent = True` also didn't help.

Passing `ssh_pkey` as `paramiko.RSAKey` object didn't help as well.

So now I'm totally lost...

Any ideas?

*PS: I'm using Python 3 via Jupiter Notebook, but pure Python 3 also doesn't work.*

*PPS: Jump server and public key file are both OK as I successfully connect to my DB through via this jump server with DBeaver*